# Veterans needed: History of ASIHTTPRequest

Tags: objective-c, frameworks, history, asihttprequest

### Prologue

In the aftermath of the [`[request release];`](http://allseeing-i.com/%5Brequest_release%5D;) article on the blog of this framework's creator and — admittedly — not being a huge fan of ASIHTTPRequest (from now on: ASI) in the first place, I wonder how/why it ever started.

The first thing I noticed, when reading the post that announced the creation of ASI as [an easy to use CFNetwork wrapper](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest-CFNetwork-wrapper-for-HTTP-requests) was the second paragraph:

> NSURLConnection is easy to use, but it provides no way to obtain information about upload progress - a pita if your application happens to involve uploading large files.

It's not absolutely trivial to get at outdated Apple reference material on actively developed and maintained API so I failed to obtain documentation on concrete classes that predate 2008 but from the image that is forming, the statement quoted above *seems to be* incorrect:

When ASI was announced, `NSURLRequest` did have a method to return the `HTTPBodyStream` — as a matter of fact, that method dates back to somewhere well before 2008, probably 2006ish but it's hard to determine because the URLs for Apple's reference changed a lot over time, which makes using archive.org quite a hassle.

---

So, after this rather long prologue, here the actual question:

Is/was it impossible to simply poll the `HTTPBodyStream` for the value of its `NSStreamFileCurrentOffsetKey` property at suitable intervals or was ASI, that behemoth of several thousand lines of CoreFoundation code, born out of a small oversight?

Regardless of that, why was it being maintained/is it being used long after the upload progress callbacks were added to the `NSURLConnectionDataDelegate` in iOS 3.0?

Especially since those resources that really do profit from monitoring upload progress should be streamed anyways...

I still see ASI recommended quite a bit here on StackOverflow if someone asks about options for downloading data — regardless of it not playing well with any of the newer Apple stuff like the Twitter framework or ARC and the warnings and static analysis issues it produces. What's up with that?

Thanks for any insights!

Answer (score 0):

I can't answer the first part of your question, but to answer this part:

> I still see ASI recommended quite a bit here on StackOverflow if
>   someone asks about options for downloading data — regardless of it not
>   playing well with any of the newer Apple stuff like the Twitter
>   framework or ARC and the warnings and static analysis issues it
>   produces. What's up with that?

Not sure exactly what you've seen, but the current git master version of ASIHTTPRequest:

- works fine with ARC (you have to disable it for the ASIHTTPRequest source files, same as you do for AFNetworking)
- does not produce any warnings with the latest release version of xcode
- does not produce any static analysis issues with the latest release version of xcode

I'm not sure about the twitter framework issue you mention, I've never seen anyone mention any issues before.

Comment: I should have clarified my statement regarding ARC: the code is not ARC, nor is porting planned. I'd deem that "unsupported" because it's more a feature of the compiler to be able to not use ARC for the processing of certain files than an accomplishment of the Framework.